# MS Teams | Images not loading up in Adaptive Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have a bot in Microsoft Teams. It displays an Adaptive Card to the user. The
Adaptive Card contains an image with URL (https://myURL.in/2.png).

```
AdaptiveImage img = new AdaptiveImage();
 img.Id = "birthDayImage";
 img.Url = url != null ? url : new Uri("https://myURL.in/2.png");
```

This image is not loading up in the app.

The URL is Teams create is 'https://in-prod.ayncgw.teams.microsoft.com/urlp/v1/url/content/https://myURL.in/2.png'.

This was working on Friday.

I believe Microsoft has changes something on their side that is causing this issue.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Could you please confirm if it is happening in Teams Classic or New Teams?

Comment: It's happening in both. Teams Classic, New Teams and even in browser.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. We tested and are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT do you have any update on this? Is the issue fixed?

Comment: At the moment, we have not received any updates from the engineering team. However, we are actively communicating with them to stay updated on the progress.  As soon as we receive any updates from them, we will notify you in this thread. Thank you!